# elemental power

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "elemental power" here simply mean "basic and fundamental power"?

Much like a work of art, a beautiful equation has among its attributes much more than attractiveness – it will have universality, simplicity, inevitability and an elemental power.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elemental) offers the relevant definition—

> having the power of a force of nature

—which would seem to make *elemental power* redundant, but [the phrase is an established one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elemental%20power&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3). The reference is not to chemical elements in the modern sense but rather to the older four-element system, first proposed by the pre-Socratic philosopher-poet Empedocles of Acragas:

> Of or pertaining to the ‘four elements’, earth, air, fire, and water, or to any one of them. [OED]

So think of the power of the ocean.

There are also some references to *occult* elemental powers, *spirits* of these four elements:

> Pertaining to the powers or agencies of physical nature. ***elemental spirits, elemental gods,*** etc.: those which are personifications of natural phenomena, or are associated with particular departments of nature. So ***elemental worship, elemental religion.*** [OED]

These are traditionally the goblin or cobold for earth, the sylph for air, the salamander for fire, and the ondine or undine or nymph for water. Pope has fun with these in his *Rape of the Lock,* terming it “the Rosicrucian doctrine of Spirits” in his [dedicatory epistle](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/9800/9800-h/9800-h.htm#section1), and Goethe has Faust invoke them in conjuring. But I do not think that meaning is in play here.

Answer (score 0):

If I came across the sentence, I would interpret it as meaning ***utility in and of itself*** - the equation can accomplish an end which is inherently useful.

But honestly it's ambiguous enough that, if it's not explained by the author, it sounds more like they're trying to sound profound than actually communicating a meaningful point.